# Building red-black tree with vector of lists in C++

Tags: c++, list, c++11, vector

```
 vector<list<Nodo<string>*>> lista;
```

i have this vector of lists and I'm trying to write a method to insert elements into it

```
  template <typename T> void HashRBT<T>:: riempimento()
{
     for(auto &it:vett_dati) 
    {   int key=it.first;
        string value=(it.second);
        int id=hashFunctionDivsion(key); 
        Nodo<T> *x=rb->searchNodo(rb->getRoot(),id);
        if(x==rb->getNillT()) 
        {
         rb->insertNodoRB(id,value);
        }

      else {  
        lista.resize(getDim());
        Nodo<T> *y= new Nodo<T>(id,value);
       lista.at(id).push_front(y); //inserimento in testa
      }
    }
    Print_Lista(); 
}
```

now in the else block is where I go to insert the elements in this vector of lists but I don't understand why if I comment the resize statement this doesn't work and I get an error like this: vector :: _ M_range_check.
I would like someone to explain to me what happens in memory?
what am i allocating with that resize?

Comment: You really don't want a vector of pointers if you can avoid it. Can't you just put the item in there directly with `emplace_front()`?

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: if `T` is not `string` then `lista.at(id).push_front(y);` will be an error. (y is `Nodo<T> *` not `Nodo<string>*`)

Comment: @tadman i can't because i have to insert in this list a series of nodes that are part of a red and black tree. the thing that I didn't understand well is how this vector of lists works and I don't understand when I go to do that resize if I am giving the dimension to the vector or to each list that I have associated with the index of the vector.

Comment: At the *absolute least* use a pointer wrapper like [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to help manage memory. I also have no idea what the rest of what you just said means.

Comment: You've got some code here, which is great, but what's missing is why any of this code exists, what it's trying to achieve, and what the desired outcome is. If you're creating a Red-Black tree you may want to skip the Standard Library containers and just build your own `struct` or `class` instead to represent the individual nodes. These trees aren't that complicated, but they can get that way if you layer in a bunch of unnecessary elements.

Comment: if you see the else block when I try to insert elements in this vector without resizing it gives me an out of range error because I am trying to access memory areas that do not exist

Comment: @tadman when I insert a node in the red and black tree if it already exists it generates a collision and I have to create a list associated with this node. I am creating a hashRBtree

Comment: Do you have a reference for the structure you're trying to build? Wikipedia usually has very complete examples to work from.

Comment: I have all the classes implemented but it is really a lot of code @tadman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the problem down and look at it without the logic of your rb tree.

```
std::vector<int> vec{10,20}; // vector of size 2
vec.at(0); // fine: element 0 exists.
vec.at(1); // fine: element 1 exists.
vec.at(2); // will throw because vector has size 2, so only elements 0 and 1
vec.resize(3); // now vector has size 3: elements 0, 1, 2
vec.at(2); // fine: element 2 exists.
```

Whether you store an `int` or a `std::list<Node<T>>` in it doesn't matter for `std::vector`'s fundamental logic.

So, if you access an element with [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) that doesn't exist you will get an error:

> `std::out_of_range` if !(pos < size()).

Similarly, [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) will not work but fail silently. Omitting the check has performance benefits.

> **Unlike std::map::operator[], this operator never inserts a new element into the container. Accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is undefined behavior.**

Comment: hello this is the explanation I wanted. Not based on my class but in a general way. Now what I didn't understand when I go to do that resize I'm going to resize the list or the vector I don't understand how I access the elements through the list. @bitmask

Comment: @mimmolg99 You can resize the vector or the list. Say you have `std::vector<std::list<int>>`. `vec.resize(n)` will be applied to `vec` which is of type `std::vector<...>` so it will resize the vector. Now you have `n` lists, which you can resize individually: `vec[2].resize(100)` resizes the list at index 2 to hold 100 `int`s.

Comment: @mimmolg99 Having said all that, an `std::list` is almost always the wrong data structure. Rethink what semantics you want. In most cases an `std::vector` is a better choice. At any rate, why an rb tree would require you to have a vector of lists is completely beyond me.

Comment: because when a node is already present in the tree this generates a collision and I have to insert this node in a list which in turn will be connected to other nodes @bitmask but anyway I don't understand why if I have less than N values I need to resize the vector of N every time.

Comment: From your op, it is not clear what `getDim()` does. You only have to resize the vector to a given size once. You likely have other errors in your code or your `lista` object goes out of scope at some point.

Comment: I solved the problem it was enough to set the size at the beginning of the method and not every time I entered into the else. thanks